# How to upload video on youtube codngiter?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload video using  codngiter library but everytime it give me error You need to authorize access before proceeding.

here is library link:-https://github.com/rahul455/youtube-data-api-codeignitor

Answer (score 0):

Did You complete Step 1? Copy Google.php into your config and add your API key? It doesn't sound like it.

https://github.com/rahul455/youtube-data-api-codeignitor/blob/master/application/config/Google.php

Comment: You have an API key? You authorised your app on YouTube's side?